# Overriding matplotlib.artist.Artist to draw complex shape

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create an Artist in matplotlib that can draw a `compound` shape that includes text and images encapsulated within a FancyBboxPatch. I have derived a class from the aforementioned FancyBboxPatch and overridden the "draw" method, but it does not seem to work.

What I am trying to achieve is an object that is drawable by matplotlib, but is more complex than the simple patches available; a bit like the concept of a compound widget in GUI design.

Here is what I tried:

```
class Cell(FancyBboxPatch):

    def __init__(self, xy, width, height, **kwargs):
        FancyBboxPatch.__init__(self, xy, width, height, **kwargs)

    def draw(self, renderer):
        print "Overridden draw method"
        FancyBboxPatch.draw(self, renderer)

        # Try drawing some simple patches and text:
        r = Rectangle((set._x, self._y), self._width, self._height)
        r.draw(renderer) # this doesn't draw

        t = Annotation("hi", (self._x, self._y))
        t.draw(renderer) # this causes an error
```

but this does not work. The rectangle does not get drawn and the Annotation throws an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transData'`

I get the feeling I am going about this the wrong way! Can I override the `draw` method this way?

TIA

Comment: Am I even going about this the right way? This is how I would approach the problem when doing something similar in a GUI environment like Android/Gtk/Qt,etc. Maybe this is not the right approach for matplotlib? Am I in the wrong mindset?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- first, you should try to add *args into **init** params and pass it also into FancyBboxPatch.**init**
- when overriding draw, you should call original draw, after (or befre) you're done with your changes because there may be some internal methods it calls that you're not aware of, check source code for FancyBboxPatch.draw

http://matplotlib.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.99.3-1/patches_8py-source.html

As I can see, FancyBboxPatch is a subclass of Patch, which is subclass of Artist, both Patch and Artist have methods draw, so you can't just simply override them without calling the original method

EDIT: I'm super blind, sorry for that, you're calling the draw method, however it is a good idea to add *args and **kwargs to any overriden methods .. try that, and perhaps call FancyBboxPatch.draw at the end of overriden method

Comment: Adding *args and moving the draw method to the end of the overridden draw made no difference...

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in syntax when you override [class methods](https://blog.devzero.com/2013/01/28/how-to-override-a-class-method-in-python/) and [instance methods](http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2014/05/19/method-overriding-in-python/). It might help you solve the problem. The call for the overridden "draw" method should thus be :

```
super(Cell,self).draw(renderer)
```

The same goes for your constructor :

```
super(Cell,self).__init__(xy, width, height, **kwargs)
```